# Python Openzwave Raspberry Pi Device not ready

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, z-wave

I'm currently trying to lock/unlock/set codes on a kwikset Zwave lock through python-openzwave on a raspberry pi running rasbian.

I installed python-openzwave on an Ubuntu VM where I can lock/unlock/set codes through a zwave controller connected to the computer. I run test command `pyozw_check -l -d /dev/ttyACM0 -t 60` to view the list of nodes on the network and I can see the controller and lock both ready to receive commands. I am able to lock/unlock/set codes on the lock through this Ubuntu VM.

However after installing python-openzwave on my raspberry pi and connecting the zwave controller to it, the test command to view lists of nodes on the network shows the controller as ready to receive commands while the lock's Ready state is set to false. When I try to issue commands to the lock through the raspberry pi, nothing happens.

This is the output from the test command on the Raspberry Pi:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/zwaveproject $ pyozw_check -l -d /dev/ttyACM0 -t 60
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Define options for device /dev/ttyACM0
Start network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Network is awaked. Talk to controller.
Get python_openzwave version : 0.4.5
Get python_openzwave config version : Original Z-Wave 3.95
Get python_openzwave flavor : git
Get openzwave version : 1.4.0
Get config path : /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/python_openzwave/ozw_config
Controller capabilities : {'primaryController'}
Controller node capabilities : {'beaming', 'listening', 'primaryController'}
Nodes in network : 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wait for network ready (60s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Network is awake. Some sleeping devices may miss. You can increase timeout to get them. But will continue.
------------------------------------------------------------
1 - Name :  ( Location :  )
 1 - Ready : True / Awake : True / Failed : False
 1 - Manufacturer : Aeotec  ( id : 0x0086 )
 1 - Product : ZW090 Z-Stick Gen5 US ( id  : 0x005a / type : 0x0101 / Version : 4)
 1 - Command classes : {'COMMAND_CLASS_BASIC', 'COMMAND_CLASS_NO_OPERATION'}
 1 - Capabilities : {'beaming', 'listening', 'primaryController'}
 1 - Neighbors : {2} / Power level : None
 1 - Is sleeping : False / Can wake-up : False / Battery level : None
------------------------------------------------------------
2 - Name :  ( Location :  )
 2 - Ready : False / Awake : True / Failed : False
 2 - Manufacturer : Kwikset  ( id : 0x0090 )
 2 - Product : Touchpad Electronic Deadbolt ( id  : 0x0001 / type : 0x0001 / Version : 4)
 2 - Command classes : {'COMMAND_CLASS_USER_CODE', 'COMMAND_CLASS_DOOR_LOCK_LOGGING', 'COMMAND_CLASS_NO_OPERATION', 'COMMAND_CLASS_DOOR_LOCK', 'COMMAND_CLASS_ALARM', 'COMMAND_CLASS_PROTECTION', 'COMMAND_CLASS_TIME_PARAMETERS', 'COMMAND_CLASS_ASSOCIATION', 'COMMAND_CLASS_VERSION', 'COMMAND_CLASS_MANUFACTURER_SPECIFIC', 'COMMAND_CLASS_CONFIGURATION', 'COMMAND_CLASS_BASIC', 'COMMAND_CLASS_BATTERY'}
 2 - Capabilities : {'frequent', 'beaming', 'routing'}
 2 - Neighbors : {1} / Power level : None
 2 - Is sleeping : False / Can wake-up : False / Battery level : 80
------------------------------------------------------------
Driver statistics : {'callbacks': 1, 'OOFCnt': 0, 'broadcastWriteCnt': 9, 'CANCnt': 0, 'badChecksum': 0, 'noack': 0, 'writeCnt': 19, 'netbusy': 0, 'broadcastReadCnt': 0, 'nondelivery': 0, 'badroutes': 0, 'retries': 0, 'routedbusy': 0, 'dropped': 6, 'ACKCnt': 19, 'SOFCnt': 25, 'NAKCnt': 0, 'ACKWaiting': 0, 'readCnt': 25, 'readAborts': 0}
------------------------------------------------------------
Stop network
Exit
```

I'm trying to figure out why the lock's ready state is set to false only on the raspberry pi. If I pull out the zstick from the raspberry pi and plug it into my Ubuntu VM, the lock's ready state is set to true.  I have excluded and included the lock through the raspberry pi and reset the controller stick. Maybe there is an extra step when working on the raspberry pi to set the device's ready state?